# Select default value in select dropdown with Angular 6

Tags: angular, forms, angular6

I would like to select default value ( 484 which is Mexico), but the first item get selected.

In the text, I print all value, and they are all OK  (`country.id === tournament.venue.country_id` condition is working)

Here is my code, I am not using reactive forms:

```
<select class="form-control select-lg" id="country_id" name="country_id" [(ngModel)]="tournament.venue.country_id">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries"
        [selected]="country.id === tournament.venue.country_id"
        [ngValue]="tournament.venue.country_id">
        {{ country.name }} {{ country.id }} {{ country.id === tournament.venue.country_id }}
    </option>
</select>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

`ngValue` should be country id

```
 [ngValue]="country.id">
```

Comment: ooooo ! Thanks !